# sort single column from dataframe by row from multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently sorting through a DataFrame containing survey data from multiple .csv files and outputting a single column from each .csv that contains the survey answers like so:

```
                                               answer
0                                                 NaN
1                                           5-6 hours
2                                        Very restful
3                                  Somewhat refreshed
4                            [Home (dorm; apartment)]
5                                     [No one; alone]
6                   [Resting; napping; doing nothing]
7   [Not applicable; was not interacting with anyone]
8                                         Quite a bit
9                                        A little bit
10                                       A little bit
11                                       A little bit
12                                            Neutral
------------------------------------------------------
                                             answer
0                                               NaN
1                                         6-7 hours
2                                  Somewhat restful
3                                Slightly refreshed
4                  [Home (dorm; apartment);Vehicle]
5                                          [Family]
6           [Commuting; traveling;Eating; drinking]
7   [Talking on the phone;Interacting on Instagram]
8                                         Very much
9                                        Not at all
10                                      Quite a bit
11                                     A little bit
12                                          Neutral
```

My goal is to get the data into this form (essentially grouping the responses by row):

```
5-6 hours
6-7 hours

Very restful
Somewhat restful

Somewhat refreshed
Slightly refreshed
```

I'm a little lost as a newbie so any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can essentially store the answers for each of the questions separately.

You can do this by iterating through the csv files and storing specific rows into given variables.

```
answer1List = []
answer2List = []

for i in range(len(csvList)):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvList[i])

    #Reading specific rows using iloc
    answer1List.append(df.iloc[1]['answer']   #Since the first answer is on the 2nd line
    answer2List.append(df.iloc[2]['answer']   #Since the 2nd answer is on the 3rd line
```

This way, your output variables will have the required answers separated out